# How to get whole (opened) document in excel through add ins?

Tags: excel, office-addins, excel-addins

I want to pass the current document (excel file) opened to API.
I tried finding on ways to do it but I found out [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/word/get-the-whole-document-from-an-add-in-for-word) which is only for word and power point and [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/excel?view=excel-js-preview) which is for reading specific data from excel. Any idea on how can I achieve that?

I am new at this and not sure where to look.
Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.